# I have upgraded Harmon.ie from version 7 to version 8. Office 365 Groups are no longer updated

Tags: harmon.ie

After the upgrade to version 8, new groups and teams are no longer added under Teams and Groups.  Additionally, new installations of Harmon.ie 8 do not show any teams or groups.  I receive no errors and have followed the setup instructions that include authorizing the App Registration.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Harmon. It's not a programming question, because you've not asked a question related to programming or included any code.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an issue we have identified, it stems from MS Graph API we call to get the Teams, it has been recently broken by Microsoft.
We have opened a ticket to Microsoft and work in parallel in getting new Team site differently.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing; however, we don't seem to have a problem getting the logged in user's groups.  I also don't see a limitation identified. Are you sure that there is a problem with the MS Graph API call?

Comment: Yeah I am sure. I even logged a bug about it that is been assigned. See: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6354  We have anyway implemented another way to get these Teams&Groups. You need to download and install our latest version from our web site.

Comment: Gotcha.  Didn't expect that you would be using the directory object endpoint.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: The work around does pull in teams now, but doesn't pull in o365 groups that do not have an associated team.  I think I understand now why you are using the Directory Object endpoint since that should pull all teams and groups.